# Difference between deploy and create-application-ref in GlassFish?

Tags: java, glassfish-4

What is the difference between deploying a web-app to GlassFish using the (asadmin) `deploy` command as opposed to using `create-application-ref`?

I read the documentation in https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf but I am not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, seems like I skipped this all section !

The asadmin create-application-ref and asadmin 
delete-application-ref subcommands enable you to add or delete targets for a 
deployed component. Because the application or module itself is stored in the central repository, adding or deleting **targets** adds or deletes the **same version of the component on different targets**.